# Make Html-Custom-Cursor the screen cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure a way to ensure a certain custom css cursor is available for the whole screen. The idea is that when the user clicks mouse down on a div, I'll attach the listeners to the document (move, up) to be able to catch events outside the browser window as well.

However, the custom cursor assigned for mouse down is lost as soon as the user moves out of the div. This doesn't happen in Mozilla when I use element.setCapture as this will also keep the current cursor active until releasing capture. Is there a way to do the same (aka keep cursor active for screen while dragging) for any (modern) browser?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question. Here is a hack you can do.

**CSS**:

```
*{ 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bEgMK/

Comment: But this doesn't seem to hold for the user case I'm looking for --> leaving the client area of the browser window/frame resets the cursor..